# sequelize mysql ssl SequelizeConnectionError: ER_HANDSHAKE_ERROR: Bad handshake

Tags: mysql, azure, ssl, sequelize.js, azure-database-mysql

I try to connect to an Azure MySQL DB with ssl.

```
new Sequelize('db', 'user', 'pw',
    {
        host: '...',
        port: '3306',
        dialect: 'mysql',
        dialectOptions: {
            insecureAuth: true,
            ssl: {
                ca: fs.readFileSync('ca.pem')
            }
        }
    }
```

However I get ...  `

> SequelizeConnectionError: ER_HANDSHAKE_ERROR: Bad handshake

I have already tried:

https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/issues/578

`

Answer (score 0):

Ensure that your credentials are in the format of user@servername; this is required for Azure Database for MySQL.

Answer (score 0):

A little late to the party but just came across this myself. [This](https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/issues/11746) thread helped me solve it. If it's an option you could also just downgrade your version of Node but that's more of a bandaid than a fix.